# scrapy AuthorSpider example confusion

Tags: python, web-crawler, closures, scrapy

I'm reading scrapy tutorial from it's official page: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Here is the code what confused me:

```
import scrapy


class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'author'

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to author pages
        for href in response.css('.author + a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def parse_author(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()

        yield {
            'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
            'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
            'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
        }
```

The key point is the following function which defined inside the function `parse_author(self, response)`:

```
def extract_with_css(query):
    return response.css(query).extract_first().strip()
```

As the tutorial said, The `parse_author` callback defines a helper function to extract and cleanup the data from a CSS query. Anyone can help understand this? When will it be called?

Comment: It gets called for the elements in the `yield` immediately below it... It saves you having to repeat the `extract_first().strip()` for each query...

Comment: thank you, I didn't read the code carefully, my fault.